# Is there some easy way how to change placeholder color by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change placeholder color by using jQuery because I want to paralyze one input.

All inputs have transparent color after focus via CSS:

```
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    color: transparent;
}
:focus::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: transparent;
}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    color: transparent;
}
:focus:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: transparent;
}
```

I tried for example this way, but nothing happened:

```
inputSelectSubCat.on('mousedown', function() {
   event.preventDefault();
})
```

But it also paralyze blur and focusin event for this input element.

PS: I read similar topics, but there are not very nice solutions for this problem. I think that must be something more easier then create  element.

Comment: No, I already checked this answers before I wrote this question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a variable and change its value with [`style.setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) method.

For example.

```
input {
  --placeholder-color: transparent
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
    color: var(--placeholder-color);
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: var(--placeholder-color);
}
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
    color: var(--placeholder-color);
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: var(--placeholder-color);
}
```

```
const input = document.querySelector('.input-class');
input.style.setProperty('--placeholder-color', '#333');
```

Comment: We have many duplicates of this question, please don't answer such frequently asked questions.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I use jQuery.